# Firebase realtime data validation rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am attempting at creating a validation rule that ensures the data written in 'user_post' is consistent with the data saved in 'user_profile'. My rule is as follows:

```
"user_post":{
      ".read":true,
      ".write":true,
        "$posts":{
          "location_id":{".validate":"newData.child('location_id').val() === root.child('user_profile').child(auth.uid).child('location_id').val()"}
        }
   }
```

However, the rule prevents a write despite location_id in 'user_profile' & 'user_post' is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Err... What I am trying to achieve is allow write if the 'location_id' is the same in both 'user_profile' & 'user_post'. If they are not the same, write is disallowed.

Comment: the write fails. It should not fail as the validation rule results in true outcome